# Set custom font in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, fonts, android-adapter

I have a fragment that loads a RecyclerView but I want to add a custom font to the TextView within one of the RecyclerView's items. Where in my adapter should I set the font? Also how exactly do I set the font?

I can't use this code,

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset((getAssets(),
            "myfont.ttf");
```

because I am not in the Activity. So how should I get the font?

This is my adapter,

```
public class DiscoverRecyclerAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscoverRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mText;
        public ViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.CardView v) {
            super(v);
            mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    public DiscoverRecyclerAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public DiscoverRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_discover, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((android.support.v7.widget.CardView)v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mText.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Where within the adapter should I set the font and how would I set the font?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where in my adapter should I set the font?

Either in `onCreateViewHolder()` or in your `ViewHolder` constructor.

> So how should I get the font?

With that code. Create the `Typeface` in the `Activity` (or fragment, if the `RecyclerView` is in a fragment). Pass the `Typeface` into the `DiscoverRecyclerAdapter`. Use the `Typeface` in `onCreateViewHolder()`, either directly or by passing it to the `ViewHolder` constructor. In particular, create precisely *one* instance of the `Typeface`, not one per row.

Answer (score 6):

this should fix this add this to your recyclerviewadapter viewHolder constructor

```
tf_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BebasNeue Regular.ttf");
            this.mainText.setTypeface(tf_regular);
```

Answer (score 0):

add in onCreateViewHolder()

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "font/Test.ttf");
    viewHolder.TextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this should be placed inside the CustomViewHolder's constructor:

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BebasNeue Regular.ttf");
this.mainText.setTypeface(font);
```

Other than that, **make sure your "fonts" folder is under "assets" and your "assets" folder is under your "main" folder (and not "res").**

Comment: like mentioned where?

Comment: Right inside the code block :) Should be placed inside the CustomViewHolders' constructor